# error : lvalue required as unary' &' operand

Tags: c++

```
// Online C++ compiler

int main() {
    int a[3]={9,8,7} ;
    std::cout << &(a+1) <<"___" <<&(a[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Why I am not able to get address values. Its showing error.

Comment: `a` can already be considered an int* so your trying to get an int** or so? What do you want to be printed?

Comment: The second one is perfectly fine. The first one is not (`a+1` is a temporary value, it has no address). Note that `a + 1 == &a[1]`, which is probably what you were trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to retrieve the pointer of an **rvalue**, ie the result of the computation (a+1). An **rvalue** is defined to be whatever  has not got an address, so it can be stored somewhere in the registry for the duration of the computation. It would be like saying `&1`, but of course 1 has no pointer. The `&` operand can thus only be used on **lvalues**, ie values which are stored at some memory address.

In your case, `a` already corresponds to a pointer to `a[0]`, so in order to print the pointer to `a[1]`, you literally just need:

```cpp
std::cout << a + 1 << std::endl;
```

Pointer arithmetics will increment the address by `x * sizeof(T)`, and since `a` is an array of `int`, it will increment the address value of `a[0]` by `sizeof(int)`, hence `4`.